# Module replacement when there is no conflict

Tags: gradle

Module replacement works well in Gradle, however it only applies when there is a conflict.
Although I understand the reason, it breaks my use-case where there is extension of configurations and the conflict happens in some but not others that I need to consume.

I have two special configurations and some module replacement:

```
configurations {
  lib // what should be bundled
  provided // what should not be bundled
  implementation.extendsFrom(lib)
  implementation.extendsFrom(provided)
}

dependencies {
  modules {
    module('javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api') {
      replacedBy('jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api', 'Javax to Jakarta')
    }
  }
}

task collectLibs(type: Copy) {
  // bundle everything from lib which is not provided (not even transitively)  
  from configurations.lib - configurations.provided
  into "$buildDir/lib"
}
```

I also use company BOM, here for example: `api platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.4')` and so I don't want to specify versions anywhere in my project.

Let's assume these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  lib 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api'
  provided 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api'
}
```

the task `dependencies` then correctly resolves `compileClasspath` and `runtimeClasspath` to `jakarta.annotation-api`, however the collected files in `build/lib` contain `javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar` even though it "should have been replaced and subtracted"

If I use module substitution instead, it works:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api') using module('jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5')
    }
}
```

However there I must specify version. Is there any possibility to force module replacement to always act?

My problem is caused by the subtraction, maybe there is a better way to find all dependencies that come from `provided` but not `lib` by looking at `runtimeClasspath`?
I tried something but it gets too complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of subtracting `provided` configuration, I can exclude everything from resolved `provided` configuration. The tricky part is to exclude not too much and not too little:

- platform must remain otherwise resolution of versions will fail
- both requested and selected must be excluded

This is not a general solution; it still requires some fiddling with configurations (`provided` must declare both `javax` and `jakarta`) but it works for me.

```
    private static excludeFromConfiguration(Configuration configuration, Configuration toExclude) {
        toExclude.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.each { dep ->
            if (dep instanceof ResolvedDependencyResult && dep.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector) {
                def isPlatform = dep.requested.attributes.keySet().any {
                    // asking for org.gradle.api.attributes.Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE does not work
                    def attribute = dep.requested.attributes.getAttribute(it)
                    return attribute == org.gradle.api.attributes.Category.ENFORCED_PLATFORM ||
                            attribute == org.gradle.api.attributes.Category.REGULAR_PLATFORM
                }

                if (!isPlatform) {
                    // we exclude both - the requested and selected because there could have been some:
                    // module replacement, dependency substitution, capability matching
                    configuration.exclude(group: dep.requested.group, module: dep.requested.module)
                    configuration.exclude(group: dep.selected.moduleVersion.group, module: dep.selected.moduleVersion.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```